# Shell script integer input

Tags: shell

I am having an issue with my script. What I want to do is depending on a integer value entered into the script on runtime, it would iterate through a file conversion split a certain amount of times before completing. The one problem that I foresee is that I will be comparing a string instead of a integer when running through the while loop portion of the script. Here is some of the code.

```
    GTF="$1"
SP=$(dirname "$SCRIPT")

echo "Welcome to this script, Please do me a favor and enter the dimensions of the original Geographical Tiff file so I do not crash myself!!"

# Read the x axis max and y axis max so we do not have any errors.

echo "X axis -> "
read XMAX
echo "Y axis -> "
read YMAX
```

the XMAX and the YMAX values need to be integers in the script in order for it to work as intended. Anyone have a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manipulate strings in a shell such as `bash` *as if* they were integers.

If you want to *ensure* it's an integer before you do anything with it, you can use regular expressions to do this, such as with:

```
echo -n "ENTER value: "
read xyzzy
if [[ ! $xyzzy =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ; then
    echo "No good"
    exit
fi
(( xyzzy = xyzzy + 1 ))
echo "Adding one gives" $xyzzy
```

That will ensure the number consists only of digits (use `^-?[0-9]+$` if you want to allow negative integers as well):

```
pax$ testprog.sh
ENTER value: 5
Adding one gives 6

pax$ testprog.sh
ENTER value: x
No good

pax$ testprog.sh
ENTER value: x55y
No good
```

If you're using a non-`bash` shell that doesn't support the regex equality, you can call an extrnal program like `grep` and check its return code.

Just remember that, if you're using something like `[[` to compare them against other values, use `-eq`, `-ne`, `-lt` and their brethren rather than `==` or `!=`.

The latter group are *string* comparisons, the former numeric ones. The `bash` man page covers this in more depth.

Comment: So to clarify, I do not need to covert the strings into integers correct? My program needs to take xy coordinates and do some arithmetic operations. The XMAX and YMAX values are there to ensure that the program does not go over those values.

So if I put the while loop and compare 2 values, it should work as intended correct?

Comment: @Taylor: yes, although remember to use numeric comparison operators. I've added that to the end of the answer. And, while you don't need to _convert_ them, it may still be a good idea to _check_ them.